# "error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Resource DesignerAttribute' attribute" while converting Xamarin project to .net MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a sample Xamarin project and tried to convert it to Maui project using these steps(https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)) but it is showing an error:-

```
error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Android.Runtime.Resource DesignerAttribute' attribute
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H203y.png)

Comment: Yep, I'm getting the same error. Haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Mixing managed and unmanaged designers in Xamarin or in MAUI will cause this

[assembly: global::Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute("MyApp.Resource", IsApplication=true)]

Comment: Could you provide some more relevant code?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve this issue by removing a lingering Resources\Resource.designer.cs file. Also make sure to comment out everything in Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: This solved my issue, Thanks!
During Xamarin.Forms to MAUI migration, I moved the Resources\Resource.designer.cs file from Android project to MAUI Android/Platforms folder. Removing this file solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @SyedAsadAli. Solution working fine for me in MAUI migration.